# Will this static class break in a multi user scenario?

Tags: c#, web-applications, extension-methods, ooad, static-classes

Say I make a static class like following with an extension method:

```
public static class MyStaticExtensionClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, SomeClass> AlgoMgmtDict
        = new Dictionary<int, SomeClass>();

    public static OutputClass ToOutput(this InputClass input)
    {
        // clears up the dict
        // does some kind of transform over the input class
        // return an OutputClass object
    }    
}
```

In a multi user system, will the state management dictionary fail to provide correct values for the transform algorithm? Will a regular class be a better design or shoving the Dictionary inside the method a better design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only three scenarios available for your dictionary: either it *must* be shared, or it *must not* be shared, or you *don't know or care*.

If it *must* be shared, you'll have to implement proper locking. But since the first thing you're doing in `ToOutput()` is to clear the dictionary, it doesn't look like sharing it will bring you many advantages.

So, we're down to the two remaining scenarios (*must not* be shared, or *don't know or care*), and in both cases it would be better to isolate the dictionary in a local variable inside `ToOutput()`:

```
public static OutputClass ToOutput(this InputClass input)
{
    Dictionary<int, SomeClass> algoMgmtDict = new Dictionary<int, SomeClass>();
    // Dictionary starts up empty, no need to clear anything.

    // Do some kind of transform over the `input` object.
    // Return an OutputClass instance.
}
```